# ¿Como obtener los últimos registros de una tabla agrupandolos por un campo especifico en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla `Historial` en mi base de datos la cual guardar el historial de renovaciones de un sitio, es decir que un sitio puede tener muchas renovaciones.

**EL PROBLEMA** 

El problema esta en que al momento de agrupar las ultimas fechas por sitio no me arroja la ultima fecha. No se si es quizas porque se esta agrupando por sitio, aunque esa es la idea, que me muestre la ultima fecha de renovacion por sitio.

**Agrupando**

[image: Agrupando por sitio(establecimiento)]

** Sin agrupar (ver id_establishment 2) deberia de agruparmelo y mostrar el ultimo registro**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podés dar un ejemplo de como debería ser la salida esperada?

Comment: Hola, deberia de mostrar 3 registros agrupando el id 2 que es el que esta "repetido" mostrando date_update_renovate 2019-01-15 02:30:00 (que seria el ultimo registro que se le hizo a ese sitio)

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 2):

Para agrupar regstros necesitas que los mismos tengan valores iguales en las columnas del select (sin considerar las funciones de agregado).

Usando la función de agregado `max()` podés quedarte con la fecha más grande y agrupando por `id_establishment`, con la fecha más grande para cada `id_establishment`.

```
Select id_establishment, max(date_update_renovate) as update_date
from history_renovate_establishment
group by id_establishment
order by id_establishment;
```

Comment: Hola juan gracias por tu respuesta, intente utilizar la consulta, que has realizado pero siguen apareciendo los mismos cuatro registros

Comment: Por eso men, ese es mi problema, la idea seria traer el 15-01 porque es la fecha mayor de ese id_establishment (2), si digo para agruparlo es por que el dia de mañana se puede renovar la fecha y quedaria 16-01 entonces me va a traer 14-01,15-01,16-01 del id_establishment(2) son 3 registros y solo necesitaria el ultimo que es el 16-01 y lo mismo sucederia con los demas sitios, no se si me hago entender.

Comment: Entonces lo que en realidad querés es una lista con el id_establishment y la fecha mas grande para ese id_establishment en la columna de date_update_renovate.

Comment: Es correcto, teniendo en cuenta que no es solamente para ese sitio en especifico sino general, (asi como tu dices), trayendo las fechas 'mas grandes' de cada sitio..... porque no es un solo sitio, son demasiados y cada uno tiene su propio historial.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde tengo entendido, puedes emplear el método MAX() para traer el último registro del campo que necesites, ejm: MAX(date_update_renovate).

Ya si lo que deseas es tener toda esa información en una sola fila, puedes intentar con un GROUP_CONCAT(), y dentro del mismo método, concatenas los campos que tiene identificadores diferente, ejm:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(date_update_renovate SEPARATOR' , ') AS fechita
```

Comment: Intente usar el max pero resulta que el solo me trae un registro... y la idea seria que trajera las fechas maximas por sitio, pero no me funciono. y no se trata de concatenar sino que es simple, traer los ultimos registros que ha tenido cada sitio (agrupandolos, porque si lo hago 'normal' me va a repetir los sitios que tengan fechas y no se trata de eso).